# Is there a declarative way to validate request parameters depending from one of request fields?

Tags: java, spring, validation, http-request-parameters

I'm looking for something like JSR-303 Validation Groups (bean validation, when you mark method argument with @Validated(GroupName.class) in controller and specify group in request class fields where needed), but it should decide how to validate at runtime depending on one of request fields.

For example, if we have controller class like this

```
@Controller
public class MyController {
    @Autowired
    private MyService myService;

    @ResponseBody
    @RequestMapping(value = "/path", method = RequestMethod.PUT)
    public ResponseVo storeDetail(/*maybe some annotation here*/ DetailRequestVo requestVo) {
        return myService.storeDetail(requestVo);
    }

    class DetailRequestVo {
        String type;
        Long weight;
        Long radius;
    }
}
```

And we want validation depending on type field value: if type = "wheel" then radius and weight fields should be presented, if type = "engine" then only weight field should be presented.

Does Spring (as of 3.2.17) provide API to implement these rules in more declarative approach? org.springframework.validation.Validator looks like not an option here, because its method `boolean supports(Class<?> clazz)` decides based on class info, not instance info.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Not sure about Spring but you can do that with plain JSR-303 using a custom Validator for the class itself... like

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target({ ElementType.TYPE })
@Constraint(validatedBy = TypeValidator.class)
@Documented
public @interface ValidType {
      ...
}

public class TypeValidator implements ConstraintValidator<ValidType , Object> {

    public boolean isValid(final Object target, final ConstraintValidatorContext context) {
        DetailRequestVo request = (DetailRequestVo) target;
        // do your checks here
}
```

and used like

```
@ValidType
class DetailRequestVo {
        String type;
        Long weight;
        Long radius;
    }
```

Since the custom Validator has access to the whole DetailRequestVo-Object you can do your check of field A depending on field B etc.

Comment: thanks for your answer. Indeed, it's a great way to reuse same checks and do them declaratively, but isn't it an overkill to declare custom annotation just to check fields in a single place?

Comment: Maybe, but to my knowledge still the simplest/most declarative one to meet your requirements